# keep a point always in the same position from the observer's field of view.

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I want a point to be in the same position for an observer. I know how to do it in a 2d coordinate system, when the system is rotated arounf the Z axis. Like this:
[image]

I want to achieve this in a 3d coordinate system, but I don't have enough knowledge to understand how to do this, because I have to consider all the 3 axes rotations.

[image]

I googled a lot, but can't find any info about this. I will be very grateful for any information.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler angles? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: @K.Jiang, yes, I'm familiar with them but I don't know how to combine them using thigonometry to achieve the result I need